# Temporarily change connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db2, connection-string, app-config

I have a DB2 environment, to which I would like to connect with Entity Framework. To do that, I need a connection string which looks like this, in the `app.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DB2Connect" connectionString="Database=my_db; UID=Username; PWD=Password;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

It doesn't seem like a good idea to have a password hardcoded into the `app.config` file, so I would like to replace it at run time, **but only temporarily!** The temporary part, is what is causing me trouble. I have successfully managed to replace the connection string, with the following code, but it's no good when the password remains in the the app.config file, afterwards:

```
private static void SaveConnectionString(string name, string connectionString)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString = connectionString;
    config.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
}
```

Comment: try above code without config.Save() line

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev I have tried that. In that case, nothing appears to happen...

Comment: use `OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath)` instead `OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)`

Comment: @Hossein that won't compile. Application is not valid, unless using `static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames`, but the `.ExecutablePath` still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am answering something different here, but if you are looking for a solution to having no/a different connection string when you build to release, you can look into:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms